# sorting my Idea in java

Tags: java

My list is not being correctly sorted. Can someone help look at this code ? I have a sort array, but it is not being sorted. I want this main method to sort it.

```
public class Main{
    public static void  main (String [] args){
        int [] sort = {3, 1, 2, 4};
        int temp = 0;
        int backIndex = sort.length;
        int index = 0;
        while(index <= sort.length ){
            if (sort[index] >= sort[backIndex]){
               temp = sort[index]; 
               sort[index] = sort[backIndex];
               sort[backIndex] = temp;
            }else{
               System.out.print(temp + "," + sort[backIndex]);
            }
            System.out.print(sort[index] + "," + sort[backIndex]);
            index++;
            backIndex--;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: "help look at this code" is not clear problem description. Please take your time and describe *specifically* problem you are having.

Comment: To update your question with more info use [edit] option.

Comment: The answer to your question is of course "yes" but that would make for a pretty dull Q&A. What *specific* question and/or problem do you have?

Comment: These articles may help improve your questions: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ["How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262527), http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at line 10. Change `int backIndex = sort.length;` to `int backIndex = sort.length-1;`, then use it in your loop: change `while(index <= sort.length )` to `while(index <= backIndex)`. Then it should work.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: so I did what you suggested and I got this as output: 0, 43, 40, 21, 2 instead of 4, 3, 2, 1...anyways let me refactor the code again. and i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know how this sorting algorithm (atleast it looks like one) is supposed to work correctly, but at least I can help you to understand the exception.

Your exception tells you that something in line 10 tries to access an index that is not existent. When executing the code in the question, sort[backIndex] will try to read sort[4]. 
However, in your array there is only an index 3, as indices start with 0.

```
Array: 3, 1, 2, 4
Index: 0, 1, 2, 3
```

This is why sort.lengh-1 works and sort.length doesn't, as 'length' will retrieve the number of objects in the array, 4, and this isn't a valid index (out of bounds --> not between 0 and 3).
In your while-loop, change the condition to either (index **<** sort.length) or (index <= sort.length **-1**), as your int index will otherwise increase to 4, causing Java to access the non-exsistent index sort[4].

Hope this helped. Read up something about the exceptions you get. Also try to ask better questions, as this will get you ask-banned pretty quickly (experience).

Comment: the code is supposed to sort the numbers. Yes I had error like ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. I tried debugging but wasn't successful so I needed help on how it will work.However i have done what was suggested, but i'm still getting error on this: if (sort[index] >= sort[backIndex])